# How to use tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory to create training,testing, validation sets?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensor, tf.keras

While I understand how to make a training and validation set as below:

```
train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE,
                                             validation_split=0.2,
                                             subset='training',
                                             seed=42)
validation_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(directory,
                                             shuffle=True,
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             image_size=IMG_SIZE,
                                             validation_split=0.2,
                                             subset='validation',
                                             seed=42)
```

If I also want a testing set, I am not sure how to do this. Like training is 80%, validation is 10% and testing is 10%. Can someone explain?

Comment: I am confused because in the documentation there is no subset for testing

Comment: You need to split it manually, it does not support what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the help of Scikit-learn for the sake of it and use Keras for rest of the activities.

The Keras function has the following arguments as you know and there is provision only to create the train and test dataset (test dataset represented by 'validation_split' in the function ; basically one and the same)

```
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='int',
    class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation='bilinear',
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
    **kwargs
)
```

From an [article](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-perform-kfold-cross-validation-with-tensorflow/) I referred, you can use it in the following way :

1. Load the data
2. Define the model (Keras)
3. Train-Test-Validation Split (Sk-learn)
4. Train, Test, Evaluate

The code is available in the link mentioned.